# Levels of Soul ( According to Arizal, Pnei Yehoshua )

Tags: talmud-gemara, mysticism-kabbalah, tractate-brachot, arizal

The Gemara in Masechet Brachot(10a) lists 5 worlds in which King David offered praises to Hashem( innards of his mother, when he was born etc.). In the Artscroll Edition one can find among the Notes a  commentary of Pnei Yehoshua who says that these "worlds" correspond to Nefesh,Ruach,Neshama,Chaya,Yechida and that one attains the Nefesh inside of the mothers womb, Ruach while being born ... Chaya with the age of Bar Mitzva etc. 
I've once read that according to the Arizal only few people merit to complete their Nefesh in this world and even less to complete the Ruach etc.. Could someone explain the differing views and how exactly according to the Arizal someone attains these higher levels?

Comment: And both of these opinions argue with both opinions in Rashi in Chagiga 12b who says: ורוחות ונשמות. חדא היא ויש מפרשין רוח היא הנשמה העשויה בדמות הגוף נשמה נשימה אליינ''א בלע''ז: http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01137.html#HtmpReportNum0021_L2